# How to set italics font in PDFBox loaded with custom font file

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox, boxable

I am using a custom font file(.ttf) and need to make the font look italics in the cell.

`PDType0Font chewyFont = PDType0Font.load(document,new File("Chewy-Regular.ttf"));`

`BaseTable table = new BaseTable(yPosition, yStartNewPage, bottomMargin, tableWidth, margin, document, page, true, drawContent); Row<PDPage> headerRow = table.createRow(20); Cell<PDPage> cell = headerRow.createCell(100, "Hello !!"); cell.setFont(chewyFont); table.draw();`

Comment: I am not sure how google sheet does it.
It only has Chewy.ttf, no italics available for download.